# Which is the right way to clone component in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I am a newbie to React. I am using react-chartjs-2 to create line chart. There are 6 different type of data with the same structure. I created a single Line chart component and cloned 5 others. Then I passed data like this:

```
let liveChart1 = <LiveChart1
                        name= {t('chart.30min')}
                        segmentType = {30}
                        currentTime={this.state.currentTime30}
                        predictedTime={this.state.predictedTime30}
                        density={this.state.density30}
                        predictedValue={this.state.predictedValue30}
                        same_anchor_params={this.state.same_anchor_params30}
                        prev_anchor_params={this.state.prev_anchor_params30}
                        historyData={this.state.historyData30}  
                        isFirst={this.state.isFirst}
                    />
```

When it is rendering and updating data, It blinks 6 times due to 6 charts. I have two problems:

- Should I create 6 different components with the same content or
  Should I create 1 component, clone it and pass different props as
  above
- Is there any methods to render 6 components at once or stop re-render
  the previous?

Here what I am using:

```
let charts = [
  liveChart1, liveChart2, liveChart3, liveChart4, liveChart5, liveChart6
];

{
  charts.map((element, index) => {
    return (<React.Fragment>{element}</React.Fragment>)
  })
}
```

Sorry for not providing the whole script!!!

Comment: i made a few adjustment according to your code. And it's not blinking. sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wescoff-1yplf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have 6 charts in a single component and when the state of each chart is changed it is re-rendering all of the charts.

The best way is to create one child component for your chart and pass your data, title, etc through props so you can reuse this component and the re-rendering problem will be solved.

Comment: Can you explain more about creating one child? Is it calling one chart in one A component and then call 6 A components?

Comment: @khangnguyen Yes exactly. That's why everyone love react because we can easily create reusable components to work with different kind of data. Your component A will be receiving props for data that is going to change i.e title, data etc